# Cannot Select the whole surface of the tabHeader in WPF dynamically populated tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Some dynamically created Tabs]

In the above image:

- You may note there is a little *rectangle box* around the tabHeader "title".
- When I click **inside** the *rectangle box*, the tab does not get selected.
- When I click outside the box, it does.

**Code C#:**

```
public class Lexicon : ObservableCollection<LexiconEntry>
{
    public String leftLanguage  { get; set; }
    public String rightLanguage { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }

    public Lexicon(String name, String leftLanguage,String rightLanguage)
    {
        this.leftLanguage = leftLanguage;
        this.rightLanguage = rightLanguage;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    public List<Lexicon> lexicons;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lexicons = new List<Lexicon>();

        lexicons.Add(new Lexicon("foo_title","russian","french"));
        lexicons.Add(new Lexicon("bar_title", "french", "english"));
        lexicons.Add(new Lexicon("baz_title", "russian", "french"));

        TheTabControl.ItemsSource = lexicons;
    }
}
```

**Xaml CODE:**

```
<Window x:Class="InterpreterNotepad.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:avalonDock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        Title="InterpreterNotepad"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" x:Name="mainWindow">
        ...
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            ...
        </Menu>
        <TabControl x:Name="TheTabControl">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TabItem Header="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- Content -->
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="bqr"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Got it, Sorry for this newbie question, I'm new to WPF. Using snoop, I saw that my *rectangle box* was actually a tabItem inside a tabItem!

I thought the dataTemplate described the template to be repeated in the tabControl, while it describes the content of each tabItem.

I Need to put:

```
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Instead of:

```
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabItem Header="{Binding name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```